# How to further transform/animate an already transformed/animated UIView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am trying to rotate with animation a UIImageView by 5° each time it is tapped. However, each time I tap it, it seems to revert back to the original angle and start the animation from there, instead of starting from where it was already. I get that transformations need to be chained so I'm doing that, however it still doesn't work:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.imgView.transform = self.imgView.transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/180*5))
    }, completion: nil)
```

I found a promising option in a variant of the animate function, but that makes it look even worse (somehow even garbles up the image):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
        self.imgView.transform = self.imgView.transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/180*5))
    }, completion: nil)
```

What am I doing wrong?

BTW the view originally has a scale and translate transformation on it which is set once in viewDidLoad:

```
        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.maxY-view.frame.midX, width: view.frame.maxX, height: view.frame.maxX)
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 14, y: 14).translatedBy(x: 0, y: 150)
```

I'm mentioning this just in case the problem has anything to do with this piece.

Answer (score 0):

increase your angle each time you call the transform

```
angel = angel + 0.5
self.imgView.transform = self.imgView.transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi/180* angel))
```

Comment: This just makes it worse :( Then each time it again jumps back to the beginning and rotates more and more. The original version was OK in that it rotated to the correct spot, however it always did it by jumping back to the original angle, then animating to the correct one. What I need for it is to start from where it was. Everything else works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is the initial translatedBy. If I take that out, it works perfectly.
So now I know, positioning of the view should always be done via frame and/or constraints, not by translatedBy.